# What are the prefixes for animal genders?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

I know the male version when describing gender of an animal or pet is 公，but I have no clue with the female version.

Comment: 母.............?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be simple, male/female: 公/母、雄/雌

> 公鸡、母鸡；公狗、母狗; 公牛、母牛。
>   雄鱼、雌鱼。

Comment: in Cantonese, female animal is called ~乸  and male animal is called ~公.  e.g. 狗公, 狗乸;  猫公, 猫乸

Comment: Glad to know something different. I don't speak Cantonese, maybe you can give another answer about it.

Answer (score 4):

In modern Chinese 公/母 is the commonest way to describe animal gender. 雄/雌 is typically used in written language. 牡/牝 is more literary. 豭/豝（boar/sow）牯/牸（ox/cow）and many other pairs originally meant the animals of either gender and extended to refer to either gender of animals. However, note that they are never used in modern Chinese now, so if you use them in talking or writing, you will have to explain it with 公/母 or something, and give others an impression of pretension.